# Is the working principle of a light bulb a "short"?

Tags: lighting

Isn't the "filament" closing the gap making a short circuit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "how lightbulbs work" is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because how light bulbs work is not a home improvement subject.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't relate to home improvement tasks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is off topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a diy question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how basic electrics work doesn't appear to 
be on topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

A bulb filament, like any load, sits between hot and netural, so I would say it *shunts* hot to neutral.  However it is supposed to have a large amount of impedance, to prevent infinite amounts of current to flow.  So "short" is not a good word here.

Constant-*voltage* systems are almost all power distributuion and use today.  In these systems, each load is responsible for creating enough impedance, on its own, to prevent a shorting condition.

However some other systems are *constant-current*, such as fluorescent, sodium, mercury or metal halide lighting, spark plugs, etc. There, a ballast is required to assure that current is limited; the lamp itself is a dead short in the full meaning of the word.  LEDs are *partially* like that, they can self-limit current somewhat, but not very well.  To get peak performance out of them, they are driven in constant-current mode.

Incandescent light bulbs didn't get the memo about "impedance". When they are cold, they are very low impedance, not quite a short, but almost.  Once they start to heat up, their resistance increases to an appropriate value for constant-voltage power.  This burst of current flow is called "inrush current".

Comment: The last paragraph is also why incandescent bulbs typically blow when turned on. This increase of resistance is non-trivial and physically detached the filament, destroying the bulb.

Comment: @Nelson Interesting.  Well, the incandescent is the only lumination device that isn't driven constant-current, so I wonder what things would be like if it was driven CC.  I suspect it would be slower to come on, but last a lot longer.

Comment: The entire incandescent bulb technology has a bunch of conspiracy surrounding it.  Apparently someone actually solved this problem and there is a bulb that has been running for [over 100 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centennial_Light).

Comment: @Nelson Yeah if you want a night light. Reducing the power to an incandescent *dramatically* increases its service life. If you intentionally take a 60W bulb and feed it at 4W levels, yeah, it won't burn out.  The centennial bulb simply takes that to extremes; note that when it cools and restarts, it lights at normal brightness, so it has a flaw that makes it drop to 4W levels on warm-up. The conspiracies are a) incandescents could've been over-designed to take longer to burn out, and b) LEDs are intentionally junk, but that last one is just China being China.

Comment: @Harper, historically, though, there was a conspiracy by light bulb manufacturers to limit bulb lifetime to increase profits.  They even fined manufacturers whose bulbs lasted too long.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoebus_cartel

Comment: @NateStrickland you bet there was.   Also, *bumping* was a factor.  From time to time, Edison would bump system voltage by a few volts to increase system capacity  He would the bulb makers "start making bulbs for 105V" and after a number of months he deemed judicious, he'd bump system voltage.  100V bulbs would burn out quicker.  The bumps weren't to sell bulbs but for system capacity, but they had that effect.

Answer (score 2):

No, a “short” is an unintended connection outside design parameters.

The bulb filament is the load on the circuit and the circuit is designed for that load, things like a fuse for overcurrent protection and correctly sized cables to limit the voltage drop etc.